# Why doesn't .Font.Reset work in Find/Replace VBA Macro?

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word

I have a particular word in my document that has various inline formatting from previous authors. I want to find that word and strip out its inline formatting. If I were using the keyboard, I would select the items one at a time, applying CTRL+Spacebar to each. Instead, I wrote a macro. *In general* I don't want to assume the nature of the inline formatting; I don't want to worry if it's bold or italics or anything else; I just want to execute a generic CTRL+Spacebar, which translates to .Font.Reset in VBA. This doesn't work, though. Here's my code, which does work, but please see the comments I added, which collectively ask why .Font.Reset doesn't work:

```
Sub Inline_Formatting_Replacement()
Dim MyDocRange As Range
Set MyDocRange = ActiveDocument.Range

With MyDocRange.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "word_with_inline_formatting"
    With .Replacement
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "word_with_inline_formatting"
        .Font.Bold = False 'I shouldn't have to use this.
        .Font.Italic = False 'I shouldn't have to use this.
        .Font.Reset 'This should work instead of using .Bold and .Italic, _
                     'but this line does nothing. Why?
    End With
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Because Font.Reset is a *method* - it performs an action. Things like Bold and Italics are *properties*. Find/Replace can only work with properties. You could "loop" the Find (without Replace) and perform Font.Reset on the search Range for each loop. There are hundreds of examples "out there" for doing that.

Comment: So, I am assuming you're saying something like Bold=adjective=property, Italic=adjective=property, Reset=verb=method, where the last one doesn't work in a Find/Replace script.

Comment: Verb=>Method/ Adj./Noun=>Class/Property are mere naming conventions. Use the *Object Browser* (F2) to know which is which - or notice / pay attention to their respective icons in the *IntelliSense* dropdown when you type that `.` dot dereferencing operator.

Comment: @CindyMeister and Mathieu Guindon , thanks for the help. I've been writing VBA macros for Word for years but still never really *understood* the language. Instead, I just hack little tiny bits of code that I find through Google searches, and I gradually debug so that a whole macro actually works, but sometimes I run into a wall because of not really understanding the difference between a method and a property--and other fundamental gaps in knowledge.

Comment: I'm still confused. The IntelliSense system had, as one of its options, .Font.Reset. The VBA editor knew I was within a With.Replacement container, which means that it knew it was actually suggesting .Replacement.Font.Reset. If that syntax does nothing here, why does it exist as an option? In other words, in what type of case *would* .Replacement.Font.Reset cause an action to be taken?

Comment: Because the `Font` *object* returned by `Replacement.Font` is the same *class* as the `Font` *object* returned by `Range.Font`: it's a full-fledged `Font` instance, but it doesn't know to preserve a *method invocation* and apply it to the `Range` being replaced, because VBA doesn't work like that: you can't *delegate* a method call like this. It's quite hard to explain without getting deep into how *delegates* work, but what you're asking of VBA is basically "invoke `Reset` at a later time against whatever `Range` you find" - it can copy *state*, but not *method calls*. HTH

Comment: @MathieuGuindon , thanks for your comments and your treatise (the latter of which mystified me until I cried Uncle and just gave up). I confess that, after all of this, what I've absorbed is that there are properties and methods and that for some reason, Find/Replace works with the former and not the latter, but I (still) don't understand why that is, though I accept it to be fact. Usually, when I code, I don't have this problem. I may have one or more code logic or syntax problem, but those are easy to fix. *This* problem, on the other hand, (almost) never arises, and it's boggling my mind.

Comment: Don't worry - I only learned about delegates when I started reading about the .NET framework, and it blew my mind too, and took a little while to sink in; delegates aren't something VBA does so the very concept of it can be hard to grasp, but if you're curious about "passing a *function* (not its result) around as a parameter", know that you can do exactly that in VB.NET (or C#).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm actually a tech. writer, not a programmer. I only know one other tech. writer besides myself who messes with VBA *at all*. Compared to almost everyone I meet, I'm a 3rd degree black belt in Word, but compared to you guys, I'm just a yellow belt. I have actually taught classes in Word to other writers, which is funny, as I'm being schooled here. Anyway, thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 3):

[As Cindy Meister pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51883925/why-doesnt-font-reset-work-in-find-replace-vba-macro#comment90719634_51883925), `Font.Reset` is a *method*, not a *property*.

You're configuring `Range.Find.Replacement.Font`, telling the object model what you want to replace and how it should be formatted. That works when you invoke read/write *properties*, because read/write properties store *state*. Methods *act* on that state.

It makes more sense when you understand how properties work - here's an example:

```
Option Explicit
Private internalState As Boolean

Public Property Get State() As Boolean
'invoked when .State is on the right-hand side of an expression, e.g. foo = obj.State
    State = internalState
End Property

Public Property Let State(ByVal value As Boolean)
'invoked when .State is on the left-hand side of an expression, e.g. obj.State = foo
'the "value" parameter is the result of the right-hand side expression.
    internalState = value
End Property
```

Imagine this `internalState` contains the information about whether the font should be **bold** or not: the `Font` property on the object returned by `Replacement` is a `Font` object, i.e. an *instance* of the `Font` class. So when you do `.Bold = False` you're *encapsulating* that value inside the internal state of that `Font` object.

Now say you also have a *method* in that imaginary class module:

```
Public Sub Reset()
    internalState = False
End Sub
```

Now I don't know what `Reset` *really* does - one would have to peek at the source code for that... or see if the documentation has anything useful:

> *Removes manual character formatting (formatting not applied using a style). For example, if you manually format a word as bold and the underlying style is plain text (not bold), the **Reset** method removes the bold format.*
>   <sub>https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/font-reset-method-word</sub>

So why doesn't it *reset* the `Font` of the `Replacement` object? It's actually a very good question: one could reasonably expect that invoking `Reset` on the `Replacement.Font` would effectively "reset" that font.

I'm not very familiar with the [ms-word](/questions/tagged/ms-word) object model (Cindy is a pro though!), but in order for the `.Reset` to work as a replacement, I believe the `Font` class would need to do something like this:

```
Option Explicit
Private doReset As Boolean

Public Property Get ShouldReset() As Boolean
    ShouldReset = doReset
End Property

Public Sub Reset()
    'does whatever it does
    '...
    doReset = True
End Sub
```

And then when the replacement is actually carried out, Word can inspect `ShouldReset` and invoke the method *on the `Font` instance of the affected `Range`* - which is a *different instance* than the `Font` instance on the `Replacement` object.

Except it wouldn't make any sense for a `Font` to do something like above, because of course if you invoke `Reset` then it *should reset* - what's missing is something like a `ReplacementFont` class that could reasonably hold that state/information... and it doesn't exist.

If VBA had functions as *first-class citizens*, then you could perhaps do something like this bastardized nonsensical pseudo-code:

```
Set .ReplacementAction = New Function(ByVal r As Range)
        r.ClearFormatting
        r.Text = "word_with_inline_formatting"
        r.Font.Reset
    End Function
```

And then when you'd go `Find.Execute`, the hypothetical `ReplacementAction` function would pass the actual `Range` as a parameter to this ...*delegated action*, and `.Reset` would operate against the target `Range.Font` *when it's invoked*, as opposed to operating on the `Replacement.Font` *when it's setup*.

Alas, VBA can't do `delegate` stuff... [or can it?](https://github.com/xxxmen/abarabone-vbaEnumeration).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that calling `Find.Replacement.Font.Reset` just clears out any replacement font information, so when you do the replace, the font is not changed.

I'm running into a similar effect, where I want to remove character styling from text globally using find/replace and I haven't found any way to do that.

`Replacement.Font`, `.Style`, etc seem to have no way of setting them to "clear out any specific font/style/etc". The only choices are to do nothing or set specific values.

As a result in my case I'll have to write a loop that finds each search hit individually and does the equivalent to ctrl-space on the resulting range. This unfortunately would be much slower than the global replace.